Error: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-image-slider-box' in React Native project"
I'm developing a React Native app and want to display an image slider using the react-native-image-slider-box library. Here is my component code:
/* eslint-disable */

// Mengimpor komponen StatusBar dari "expo-status-bar" untuk mengatur status bar pada aplikasi
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
// Mengimpor komponen SliderBox dari "react-native-image-slider-box" untuk membuat slider gambar
import { SliderBox } from "react-native-image-slider-box";
// Mengimpor komponen StyleSheet, Text, dan View dari "react-native" untuk pengaturan gaya dan struktur tampilan
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
// Mengimpor fungsi getApiPopuler dari file api untuk mengambil data film populer dari TMDB API
import { getApiPopuler } from "../Request/api";
// Mengimpor hooks useEffect dan useState dari React untuk pengaturan efek samping dan state pada komponen
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// Mendeklarasikan komponen utama HomeScree
export default function HomeScree() {
  // Mendeklarasikan state getDataImageSlider untuk menyimpan URL gambar yang akan ditampilkan di slider
  const [getDataImageSlider, setGetDataImageSlider] = useState([]);

  // useEffect untuk menjalankan fungsi getApiPopuler saat komponen pertama kali di-render
  useEffect(() => {
    getApiPopuler()
      .then((movies) => {
        // Inisialisasi array kosong untuk menyimpan URL gambar
        let images = [];
        // Looping melalui data film untuk mendapatkan path poster dari setiap film
        for (let movie = 0; movie < movies.length; movie++) {
          images.push(
            `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movies[movie]["poster_path"]}`
          );
        }
        // Memperbarui state getDataImageSlider dengan URL gambar
        setGetDataImageSlider(images);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // Menangkap error jika ada masalah dalam pengambilan data dari API
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  // Mengembalikan tampilan komponen dengan teks "Hello" dan StatusBar
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* Teks sederhana untuk menampilkan "Hello" */}
      <Text>Hello</Text>
      {/* Mengatur status bar secara otomatis sesuai platform */}
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

// Mendeklarasikan StyleSheet untuk mengatur gaya pada komponen
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1, // Membuat kontainer menempati seluruh layar
    backgroundColor: "#fff", // Mengatur warna latar belakang menjadi putih
    alignItems: "center", // Menyusun isi kontainer di tengah secara horizontal
    justifyContent: "center", // Menyusun isi kontainer di tengah secara vertikal
  },
});


However, I get the following error:
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-image-slider-box'. 'd:/progam-code/codepolitan/react-native-project/react-native-project/node_modules/react-native-image-slider-box/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try npm i --save-dev @types/react-native-image-slider-box if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'react-native-image-slider-box';ts(7016)
module "d:/progam-code/codepolitan/react-native-project/react-native-project/node_modules/react-native-image-slider-box/index"
I've done a lot of things to make react-native-image-slider-box readable but I still haven't found a way out. can anyone provide an answer.
Please help
